# TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

problem

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

component1

```html
<div id="formkeyRefId" #formkeyRefId (click)="test.reloadContent(data.value)> </div>
<ng-container>
    <app-component2  #test [data]="data.value" ></app-component2>
</ng-container>
</div>
```

```
           export class Component1 implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

            @ViewChild('formkeyRefId', { static: false }) formkeyRefId: ElementRef;

            constructor() { }

            ngOnInit() { }


            ngAfterViewInit() {

                console.log(this.formkeyRefId.nativeElement);
                this.formkeyRefId.nativeElement.click();
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log(this.formkeyRefId.nativeElement.id);
                    this.formkeyRefId.nativeElement.click();
                  }, 5000);



            }
```

component 2 app-component2

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter ,ElementRef, ViewChild,AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

export class Component2 implements OnInit,AfterContentInit {
    @ViewChild('formkeyRefId',{static: false}) formkeyRefId: ElementRef;

    constructor(public myElement: ElementRef){}
      this.afterViewInitExecuted = false; 
     ngAfterContentInit() {
      this.afterViewInitExecuted = true; 
   }

    formEventEmitter(event) {

        if (event && this.afterViewInitExecuted) {
           setTimeout(() => {
              console.log(this.formkeyRefId.nativeElement);
            }, 5000);

             //this.formkeyRefId.nativeElement.click();
            //const  el: HTMLElement = this.myDiv.nativeElement;
            //e1.click();
        }

        reloadContent() {
             getdata();
        }



}
```

tried to test whether id exist in another component

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.afterViewInitExecuted = true; 
 console.log(this.formkeyRefId);  Output Undefined
}
```

- I Need to Trigger click function `reloadContent` in component 1 .
- How to Access Id form another component using #formkeyRefId
- I can access elementref in same component but not in another component.
- any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: is the HTML valid? in your example, there is an invalid </i> tag after the div!

Comment: yes  html is valid

Comment: But `component2`, with the `@ViewChild`, is inside `component1` that also contains `#formkeyRefId`... ViewChild looks for elements within the same component, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: You also have missing quotes in your html sample. Should be `(click)="test.reloadContent(data.value)">` When is formEventEmitter event being called? There is also no component definition for the Component2 and no data property so without more context It'll be hard to help out.

Comment: There is no syntax error ,code is working fine only issue exception in native element

Answer (score 0):

It appears your click event is missing a closing quote.

Change:

```
(click)="test.reloadContent(data.value)
```

To:

```
(click)="test.reloadContent(data.value)"
```

Comment: Ok, I can't seem to reproduce your error once that is fixed. Could you create a stackBlitz that generates the same error?

Comment: I can access elementref in same component but not in another component.

Answer (score 0):

I think the function is being executed before the lifecilycle AfterViewInit executes. 
Try adding a flag indicating that the AfterViewInit have already been executed.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter ,ElementRef, ViewChild,AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

export class Component2 implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('formkeyRefId',{static: false}) formkeyRefId: ElementRef;

    prívate afterViewInitExecuted = false;

    constructor(public myElement: ElementRef){}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.afterViewInitExecuted = true; 
    }

    formEventEmitter(event) {
        if (event && this.afterViewInitExecuted) {
            this.formkeyRefId.nativeElement.click();
            //const  el: HTMLElement = this.myDiv.nativeElement;
            //e1.click();
        }

        reloadContent() {
            getdata();
        }



}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but sometimes during the compilation or when the component is instantiated a click event could be triggered. Try my solution and if doesn't work I will investigate more and find another solution.

Comment: I can access elementref in same component but not in another component.

Comment: Why do you need to access the elementRef in another component?

Comment: modal component has no relationship with component 1 , compon 1 i tried @output eventemitter but doesnt work

Comment: Try using a service to communicate between components: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service